# specificing destination directory in nsis (zipped installation)

Tags: nsis

I'm new to NSIS and creating one installer for our project.

The requirement is: there are 1 folder and 2 exes needs to be installed as part installation. These exes are created using nsis (`Y.exe`, `Z.exe`). These exes should be installed in different destination folder. I've tried this two approches:

- **Approach 1**:
  in script these variables assigned

  ```
  RUN_Y C:\Installer\misc_exe\y.exe
  RUN_Z C:\Installer\misc_exe\y.exe


  Y_INSTALL_DIR INSTDIR\Y\ # INSTDIR is specified by user during folder installation
  Z_INSTALL_DIR INSTDIR\Z\ # INSTDIR is specified by user during folder installation

  # calling this at the time exe installation
  setoutpath SetOutpath "${Y_INSTALL_DIR}"
  ExecWait '"${RUN_Y}"'
  setoutpath SetOutpath "${Z_INSTALL_DIR}"
  ExecWait '"${RUN_Z}"'
  ```

  Problem is, the destination folder is always coming as `C:\Installer\misc_exe\` , whereas it should be `C:\Y\`. How can I fix it?
- **Approach 2**:

  While creating the zipped folder to exe, I gave destination folder as `$INSTDIR/Y/` and `$INSTDIR/Z/`,  and I think, this `$INSTDIR` is taken from the 1st folder installation. But, its not working that way.

can anyone help with me with how can I do specific folder installation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but to set target directory use

```
InstallDir "C:\Y\"
```

command.